# On windows phone form panel cannot scroll when keyboard shown

Tags: windows-phone-8, scroll, sencha-touch, soft-keyboard, formpanel

I create a app use Sencha Touch2.3, on Windows Phone (Nokia Lumia 520, IE mobile 10 ) formpanel can not scroll if keyboard shown. But I have a long formpanel, can not scroll will very inconvenient.
I find all formpanel can not scroll when keyboard shown in official examples.

Now, how can I scroll formpanel when keyboard shown?

Comment: I think, you can not open keyboard, once you lost focus from any textbox or any control in which you can enter text.

Comment: focus on a textfield, now keyboard shown, then drag the formpanel.
keyboard still opened, but the formpanel can not scroll.